# Capture screen via greasemonkey/scriptish/etc

Tags: screenshot, greasemonkey, scriptish

I need to create a script for greasemonkey/scriptish/etc which would do some actions and at the end of script I need to capture a result screen.

How can I take screenshot via script?

Answer (score 4):

As Greasemonkey and Scriptish are basically just executing Javascript, you need to search a workaround which uses this language.

The solution is to use [HTML5 Canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp), and this can be easily achieved using libraries like [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots) may help you too.